# WPF TabControl ContentTemplate doesn't render on Windows XP the same as Windows 7

Tags: wpf, wpf-4.0

I have a TabControl that looks like this:

```
<TabControl x:Name="tabPlaintiffs" 
                ItemsSource="{Binding CivilPaper.Plaintiffs}" 
                ContentTemplate="{DynamicResource PersonTemplate}" 
                SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPerson, Converter={StaticResource PersonRoleToPerson}, Mode=OneWayToSource}" 
                Margin="5" />
```

The ContentTemplate looks like this:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="PersonTemplate">
                <Grid Background="#FF4EFF00">
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
```

On Windows 7, it renders like this:
[image]

On Windows XP SP3, it renders (or really doesn't render!) like this:
[image]

What is causing the difference?

***EDIT***: Removed the ItemsTemplate and removed all the databinding in the ContentTemplate to rule out all sorts of things.

Comment: If I remove the SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPerson, Converter={StaticResource PersonRoleToPerson}, Mode=OneWayToSource}" it works.  Is this a StaticResource vs. DynamicResource thing? Why would this be different on XP?

Comment: The ValueConverter fires 2x on Windows XP, but only once on Windows 7. Ridiculous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately, it turned out that Windows 7 handles the ValueConverter differently than does Windows XP.  If I removed:

```
SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPerson, Converter={StaticResource PersonRoleToPerson}, Mode=OneWayToSource}"
```

then I got all the proper templating.  The issue was in the ValueConverter, although Windows XP was firing it multiple times, while Windows 7 only fired it once at the time the underlying collection notified of it's change (as it should!)

My ValueConverter initially returned null in both Convert and ConvertBack (because it was OneWayToSource I only needed ConvertBack). If either method didn't satisfy the type check on the object, null was returned.  I now believe this to be a bad practice.  Instead it should ultimately return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue if you fall all the way through:

```
public class PlaintiffRoleToPerson : IValueConverter
    {

        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            var plaintiff = value as Plaintiff;
            if (plaintiff != null)
            {
                return plaintiff.Person;
            }

            return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
        }

    }
```

Why Windows 7 handled that differently than Windows XP is still a mystery, but I now have everything working.  I'm counting down the days until Windows XP hits end of support and I can drop it from our supported OSes.

Answer (score 1):

It's going to be very difficult for anyone, even someone intimately familiar with the code (I.e. you)  tofind the bug among such much code.

I suggest you debug your application by:

1. Verify the same runtime is being used in both machines.
2. Create a new empty control and add elements one by one, until it stops working on XP. It may be that one of the components you're using does not support it and you need to use something else.

Comment: Point taken... I was going for completeness, but it was too much XAML to expect people to look through.  I've edited it down to a much, much smaller bit.  And I've verified the same runtime on both machines.